# What do I do wrong and the second button acts weird?

Tags: java, button, location, size, frame

I know the code is bad and easy. I am a starter and need some help. I want to add a second button to my code. I feel like I changed the coordinates of the button so it doesn't "fall" on the first one. Any suggestions? (Also, .this is a bit unknown to me so I just copy - pasted it hoping it doesnt affect the second button. I feel like it has to do with .this and the coordinates of the button I entered).

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class CalculatorGUI extends Frame implements ActionListener

{

static Operand op;
TextField display;
Button button0;
Button button1;
public CalculatorGUI(String title, Operand op)
{               
    super(title);
    CalculatorGUI.op = op;
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    this.setBackground(Color.blue);
    button0 = new Button("0");
    button0.setBounds(64, 265, 35, 28);
    button0.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    button0.setForeground(Color.blue);
    button0.setFocusable(false);
    button0.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(button0);
    this.setSize(283,320);
    this.setLocation(40,30);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    
    button1 = new Button("1");
    button1.setBounds(64, 230, 35, 28);
    button1.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    button1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    button1.setFocusable(false);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(button1);
    this.setSize(283,320);
    this.setLocation(40,30);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    
    this.addWindowListener(new CloseWindowAndExit());
    display = new TextField("");
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setBounds(13, 55, 257, 30);
    this.add(display);
    
}

class CloseWindowAndExit extends WindowAdapter
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent closeWindowAndExit)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    
    if(e.getSource()==button0) 
    {
      display.setText("Button0 is pressed");
      CalculatorGUI.op.addDigit('0');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't use a `null` layout and don't set the bounds of components yourself. Use [Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not add buttons directly to the main frame. Instead, create another panel and add the buttons to it:

```
    Panel newPanel = new Panel(new GridBagLayout());

    Button button0 = new Button("BUTTON_0");
    button0.setBounds(10, 265, 30, 30);
    button0.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    button0.setForeground(Color.blue);
    button0.setFocusable(false);

    Button button1 = new Button("BUTTON_1");
    button1.setBounds(10, 265, 30, 30);
    button1.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    button1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    button1.setFocusable(false);

    newPanel.add(button0);
    newPanel.add(button1);

    this.add(newPanel);
```